# Removing the loop attribute from a video not working with jQuery on https://workswith.silabs.com/home

Tags: html, jquery, video

I'm trying to remove the loop from the video banner on this website: https://workswith.silabs.com/home

I tried removing the loop via jQuery but it didn't work but I'm guessing I need to target the video container:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('.noloop video').removeAttr('loop');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your current selector isn't matching any elements. Try `$('.home-page video')` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried targeting the video player class $('.video-element video') but still no luck.

Comment: try just `$('.video-element').prop('loop', false)` iirc loop (and other video attributes) are a bit weird

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.